# I want to create Radio Button in swift 3.0?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, dlradiobutton

I need to create radio buttons (single choice) . I did not find anything useful for swift.

Comment: I would encourage you to stop looking for direct code on SO and try to understand the coding logic. Radio buttons are just UIButton with an image, which you can change on selection/nonselection.

Answer (score 1):

Radio buttons are not available in iphone SDK. You just use an image inside UIButton(search for PNG images). You can find many RadioButton images.... Also check this Github tutorial https://github.com/DavydLiu/DLRadioButton